# Parsing expressions ! chain of operators

Tags: parsing, expression, grammar, greedy, lepl

hi I know how to parse expressions (incl. brackets).
But normally parsing expressions assumes "operand operator operand". 
F.e. :

```
 5 + 12
 ( 5 * 6 ) + 11
 ( 3 + 4 ) + ( 5 * 2)
```

As you can see the values are always two.
What I'm looking for is mechanism (grammar) than can parse chain of similar operators as a single item i.e. greedy
F.e. let say I have the following expression :

```
5 + 4 + 2 + 7 * 6 * 2

=> sum(5 + 4 + 2) 
+ 
=> mult(7 * 6 * 2)
```

I want the parser to gobble the sum as one single "action", the same for multiplication.

Here is one example of NON-working grammar, but may be you can get the idea what I want to do (python  - LEPL module) :

```
def build_grammar2(self):
    spaces = Token('[ \t]+')[:]
    plus = Token('\+')
    left_bracket = Token('\(')
    right_bracket = Token('\)')
    mult = Token('\*')
    bit_var = Token('[a-zA-Z0-9_!\?]+')

#   with Separator(~spaces):

    expr, group2 = Delayed(), Delayed()

    mul_node = bit_var & (~mult & bit_var)[1:] > Node
    add_node = bit_var & (~plus & bit_var)[1:] > Node
    node = mul_node | add_node

    parens = ~left_bracket & expr & ~right_bracket

    group1 = parens | node
    add = group1 & ~plus & group2 > Node
    group2 +=  group1 | add
    mul = group2 & ~mult & expr > Node
    expr +=  group2 | mul

    self.grammar = expr
```

Comment: If you don't specify the grammar formalism, the question is too broad to answer.  (Unless you feel that it is useful to have  the answer "find a parser which lets you use Kleene stars and then use `term ('+' term)*`".)

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much what you get with pyparsing:

```
import pyparsing as pp

add_op = pp.oneOf("+ -")
mul_op = pp.oneOf("* /")

operand = pp.pyparsing_common.number | pp.pyparsing_common.identifier

arith = pp.infixNotation(operand, 
                [
                ("-", 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT),
                (mul_op, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT),
                (add_op, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT),
                ])

print(arith.parseString("1+2-3+X*-7*6+Y*(3+2)").asList())
```

prints

```
[[1, '+', 2, '-', 3, '+', ['X', '*', ['-', 7], '*', 6], '+', ['Y', '*', [3, '+', 2]]]]
```

If you just parse numbers, you can make the parser also do parse-time eval by adding parse actions to each level of precedence (`pp.pyparsing_common.number` auto-converts numeric strings to int or float):

```
operand = pp.pyparsing_common.number

op_fn = {
    '*': lambda a,b: a*b,
    '/': lambda a,b: a/b,
    '+': lambda a,b: a+b,
    '-': lambda a,b: a-b,
    }.get
def binop(t):
    t_iter = iter(t[0])
    ret = next(t_iter)
    for op, val in zip(t_iter, t_iter):
        ret = op_fn(op)(ret, val)
    return ret

arith = pp.infixNotation(operand, 
                [
                ("-", 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT, lambda t: -t[1]),
                (mul_op, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, binop),
                (add_op, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, binop),
                ])


print(arith.parseString("1+2-3+8*-7*6+4*(3+2)"))
```

Prints:

```
[-316]
```

Comment: this is not greedy exprs. I already do that. if it is "1+2+3+ ....". Then it gets parsed as [ [+, 1, 2, 3], + ... ]

Comment: What do you do if it is "1+2-3+4"? or "5*2/3*6"? You can't really group by operator when multiple operators have the same precedence level.

Comment: gobble it left to right, [+, 1,2,3,4]; [ * , [ / , [*,5,2], 3] , 6]